# Why is it that I can ssh in but not out?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, connection

Why is it that I can ssh into another server but when I tried to ssh but it goes into timeout and failed?

```
ubi@xserver: ssh lil@yserver
Password: 
Last login: Thu Jan 30 16:10:39 2014 from xserver
lil@yserver:~> ssh ubi@xserver
_
```

I've tried ssh with option `-A` but it's not working:

```
lil@yserver:~ # ssh -A ubi@xserver
^C
```

The ssh daemon is running:

```
lil@yserver:~ # rcsshd reload
Reload service sshd                                                                                                                 
done
lil@yserver:~ # rcsshd restart
Shutting down the listening SSH daemon                                                                                                  
done
Starting SSH daemon                                                                                                                 
done
lil@yserver:~ # ssh ubi@xserver
^C
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try finding in `man ssh` that there exists a verbose mode?

Comment: Are you sure xserver is running sshd?

Comment: I agree with Slowki - could be that sshd isnt running on xserver *or* xserver has a firewall running that's blocking port the ssh port (usually 22)

Comment: On xserver run `ps ax | grep ssh` and `iptables -L` and you can answer both of FreudianSlip's questions :)

Comment: Try running ssh with `-vvv` to show where it's sticking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others explained, you need an SSH server running on **xserver** for this to work.

**If you're able to `ssh ubi@xserver` from *other* hosts** but not as lil@yserver, it could be any number of things, including but not limited to these common causes:

- xserver resolves to a different IP address on yserver - try `ping xserver` on yserver and on the host which can reach xserver.
- xserver could have firewall rules set up to allow connections from a whitelist which does not include yserver.